# URI construction for REST API and use of verbs as resource?

Tags: rest, uri

I have two questions.

1) I have a issue of understanding the correct URL construction for a REST API. For example,

```
https://api.context.io/lite/users/id/email_accounts/label/folders/folder/messages/message_id
```

Here as you can see the folder comes under folders resource and message_id comes under messages. Is it necessary to show the parent resource or collection. Will it be wrong to have a URL such as this?

```
https://api.context.io/lite/userid/folderid/message_id
```

Here, the userid, folderid and message_id maybe would indicate as integers or some other value. Of course with the values the URL doesn't make sense, but does it matter in m2m transaction? What is the best way to construct the URL?

2) Is it ok to have 'verbs' in the URL? I have seen the following urls which has verbs such as 'move', 'send' in the URL. Is that correct? If it is wrong, should we do everything such as 'search' using parameters only?

```
POST https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages/{message_id}/move
POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send
```

Please share your thoughts. I read lots of articles on these. Yet it seems to be more of a personal choose rather than an Industry standard. What would Dr. Fielding would recommend?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) It's typically best to be explicit about the display of your rested resources. Thus, it makes sense to follow the `collection/:id/sub-collection/:id` paradigm with your API.

2) It's considered an anti-pattern in the REST world to use anything other than nouns for your collections in your URIs. That's because REST best practices expect your "verbiage" to come in the form of HTTP verbs, and not something you've decided to declare on your own. This isn't a REST constraint by any means, but it's considered the best possible implementation, and allows developers to keep things consistent.

The HTTP verbs GET POST PUT and DELETE are suitable for any need your program may have. Oftentimes, if you feel you "need more verbs" in order to successfully implement a feature, it really means you need to expand your thinking of the resource on which that call is being made.

For example: if I wanted to login a user, my first thought may be to put that action on the `User` class via a `User#login` method. That'd get pretty weird, though, right? We're using a verb, and we now know that's a REST anti-pattern.

Instead, what if we created an associated `Session` class? Now we can conveniently call `Session#create` on a new instance of the model (that's associated with `User`) and stay RESTful as hell!

I really hope this helps. Remember: when in doubt, keep in mind that no matter what you're doing, the community has found a way to keep things RESTful, as there are some BIG OL' applications out there that adhere pretty strictly to the rules of REST.

**UPDATE**

Why not use a class method? I haven't seen your code, but I'm assuming you're using something like rails for your api.

You could do the following:

```
///items/index.html.erb
<% form_tag items_path, method: :get do %>
<p>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
</p>
<% end %>

///items_controller.rb
def index
  @items = Item.search(params[:search])
end

///models/item.rb
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, conditions: ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

This is obviously fairly vague object naming, but I think you'll get the idea. That way, you're always using a GET HTTP verb, and doing it in a restful manner. The other option, yes, is to use query params. This helps you avoid doing that.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer Collin. I was wondering how to implement move and search functions. As you have stated, for search, I could do something like this ->
`POST \Collection\Filter` 
Here we could specify the correct filter and would eventually return the filtered items (searched items) right? But POST is used for resource creation mainly and here the better request method would be GET. However we can't send payload for GET unless we use query parameters :( . Moving stuff is another issue where I can't think of any intermediate state to use.

Comment: I've updated my original answer to try and help out more!